# How can i change my database when using radio button in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have problem with radio button function. I manage to add the value from radio button to database when create a new user.jsp. But when I try to change the value in edit jsp the value did not change. I manage to set the radio button in edit mode to load according to database, but when I change data by clicking another radio button, it seems nothing changes in the database. Can anyone give me an example or any solution?

Here is my jsp code for the radio button:

```
<tr>
                        <td width="125" class="adminDetail">Type :</td>
                      <c:if test="${actionBean.mode eq 'new'  }">
                        <td class="adminInput">
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="locally" value="0"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('show');"  />Local
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="ldap" value="1"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('hide');"/>LDAP
                         </td>
                        </c:if>

                         <c:if test="${actionBean.mode eq 'edit' }">
                        <c:if test="${user.type eq '0' }">
                        <td class="adminInput">
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="locally" value="0"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('show').checked" />Local
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="ldap" value="1"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('hide');"/>LDAP
                            </td>
                         </c:if>


                     <c:if test="${user.type eq '1' }">
                        <td class="adminInput">
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="locally"  value="0" onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('show');"/>Local
                            <stripes:radio name="type" id="ldap"  value="1"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('hide').checked" />LDAP
                         </td>
                         </c:if>
                      </c:if>

                    </tr>
```

i'll already try to change it like this but it seem nothing change in database

```
<c:if test="${actionBean.mode eq 'edit' }">
                    <c:if test="${user.type eq '0' }">
                    <td class="adminInput">
                        <stripes:radio name="type" id="locally0" value="0"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('show').checked" />Local
                        <stripes:radio name="type" id="ldap0" value="1"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('hide');"/>LDAP
                        </td>
                     </c:if>


                 <c:if test="${user.type eq '1' }">
                    <td class="adminInput">
                        <stripes:radio name="type" id="locally1"  value="0" onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('show');"/>Local
                        <stripes:radio name="type" id="ldap1"  value="1"  onclick="Javascript:showAndHide('hide').checked" />LDAP
                     </td>
                     </c:if>
                  </c:if>
```

Comment: thanks @Peter Horvath for correcting my english

Answer (score 0):

ids should be unique...you have numerous "ldap" & "locally" ids  rename them to ldap0, ldap1, etc.

Comment: i try to change in edit mode for locally and ldap id using ldap0 and ldap 1 and locally0 and locally1 i still cant change the database value in edit jsp

Comment: @Putra in your code you have two main if tags. If two of them are true, the HTML inside <c:if> will appear on the page, it will cause problem, because html page only can have unique ids.

Comment: @player889 i already change to unique id but still didnt work..can u give me any example to understand it more...

Comment: @Putra "Javascript:showAndHide('hide').checked" i do not know what is this ( calling showAndHide function ? ) and in your javascript i do not think it relates with your html page with check() and uncheck() functions by looking your code